# How i can use objects as parametrs for imported methods in jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have set ModelAndView object like

```
modelv.addObject("document", document);
```

then I have been imported additional helper in my JSP

```
<%@ page import="com.publishing.util.DateUtil" %>
```

and then i'm trying to use document field as a parametr like this

```
<p><% DateUtil.TimestampToSpecificString(document.pub_date) %></p>
```

and IDEA says me that document didn't resolve

> Stacktrace
>
> An error occurred at line: [44] in the jsp file:
>   [/WEB-INF/views/jsp/admin/document_card.jsp] document.pub_date cannot
>   be resolved to a type 41:
>   РћРїСѓР±Р»РёРєРѕРІР°РЅРёРµ 42:                 
>  43:
>
> РЈРґР°Р»РµРЅРѕ
>
> 44:
>
> Р”Р°С‚Р° Рё РІСЂРµРјСЏ СЌР».РїСѓР±. <%
>   DateUtil.TimestampToSpecificString(document.pub_date); %>
>
> 45:
>
> РњРµСЃС‚Рѕ РѕРїСѓР±Р»РёРєРѕРІР°РЅРёСЏ
>   РЎР°Р№С‚
>
> 46:  47:
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:473)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

View

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<%@ page import="com.publishing.util.DateUtil" %>

<p><% DateUtil.TimestampToSpecificString(document.pub_date) %></p>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/search", "/search/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSearch(ModelMap model,
                               HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               HttpSession session) throws IOException, 

ServletException {

Documents documents = new Documents(); //some fields there

modelv.addObject("documents", documents);

return modelv;

}
```

DateUtil

```
public class DateUtil {

 public static String TimestampToSpecificString(Timestamp timestamp) {
   //some code here...
}

}
```

Comment: Show the stack trace too.

Comment: Please post your model and view class  and jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the object you set in ModelView by using `request.getAttribute` method.
i.e

```
<% Documents document = (Documents)request.getAttribute("document"); %>
```

Now as you have document object available in your jsp page you can use it for retrieving any field, in your case 'pub_date'.

```
<% DateUtil.TimestampToSpecificString(document.pub_date) %>
```

> Don't forget to import Documents class in your jsp page.